# Rails e-commerce gem with MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been looking for an e-commerce gem for Rails. But the ones I found are all based on sqlite. I am used to mysql. Are there any good gems which use mysql or any way which would allow me to use spree with mysql?

Comment: Spree works fine with MySQL.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find big list of e-commerce gems [Ruby-Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/#E-Commerce_and_Payments)

Migrate to any other relational database in RoR is also very easy. So I would look behind databases.

Answer (score 0):

[Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) is a complete open source e-commerce solution written by Rails. It uses ActiveRecord which allows you to switch to different SQL database solutions, e.g. `mysql`.